# Which SQL collation can I use to convert special characters for use in R scripts?

Tags: sql, r

When executing R scripts that contain certain special characters, such as ***à*** or ***é***, I get errors saying that the expression cannot be cast to a factor.

Is there an R-safe collation I can use to convert the SQL column in question that contains these special characters?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed for a 2nd time, after @PoGibas already did).

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, the standard collations didn't appear to translate *all* the special characters needed to safely cast the strings in R.

The best collation I've found is:

```
SELECT (PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI) as FIXEDCOLUMN from YOURTABLE
```

That's shorthand for Code Page 1253 (Modern Greek), Case and Accent insensitive.